# Filtering non-trivial loggers in Boost.Log?

Tags: c++, logging, boost, filtering

I'm trying to figure out how to enable a simple filter in combination with BOOST_LOG_SEV.

For example, if I set something like this up:

```
enum class SeverityLevel {
  Foo,
  Bar
};

boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<SeverityLevel> slg;

BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, SeverityLevel::Foo) << "Foo log record";
BOOST_LOG_SEV(slg, SeverityLevel::Bar) << "Bar log record";
```

I'd like to be able to add something like this:

```
slg.set_minimum_severity(SeverityLevel::Bar);  // Filter out Foo logs
```

The Boost.Log docs jump rather quickly from filtering on trivial logs to much more complicated cases.

Answer (score 1):

First, a little secret you may want to know about reading the boost log documentation, is that the code examples are much more complete than the summaries on the doc pages. If I understand you right you should be happy with the example from

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_filtering.cpp

Look for the set_filter line, and adapt it to:

```
sink->set_filter(severity >= SeverityLevel::Bar);
```

For more advanced filters I just asked a related question on boost users mailing list:

http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2013/10/80211.php

Comment: Johan, I'm having trouble filtering on severity.  I've exhausted all tutorials, documents, examples, SO Questions.  Because I'm just learning Boost I find myself swimming in terms and options that make me wonder if I'm even on the right track.  My question is here: stackoverflow.com/q/29707017/1735836